# sql server read xml without inner tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, tags

i m reading an xml, but i have a problem when i want to read it without its inner(child) tags.
for example:

```
DECLARE @XMLToParse  XML

SET @XMLToParse =   '<Animals>
                       <LandAnimals>
                        <Animal>Baboon</Animal>
                        <Animal>Yak
                            <d>asd</d>
                        </Animal>
                        <Animal>Zebra</Animal>
                       </LandAnimals>
                    </Animals>'

SELECT  xmlData.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Animal
FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Animals/LandAnimals/Animal') xmlData(A)
```

this query extracts on the second record 'Yak asd', but i need only 'Yak'.
how can i fix it?

thank you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your call on `.value()` to get the `text()`:

```
SELECT  xmlData.A.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Animal
FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Animals/LandAnimals/Animal') xmlData(A)
```

Comment: thank you very much! and so, are there any others options ilke 'text()'?

Comment: @user3061212 What other options? You might use strange *work-arounds* but why?

Comment: @user3061212 The `/text()` is the content which is the real textual content of an element. Reading the `.` with `.value()` will read the entire tree *below* the context node. You might read about `.value('data(...)')` if this is your intention. But in your case you are just not interested in lower elements...

Answer (score 2):

Specify `text()`

```
SELECT  xmlData.A.value('./text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Animal
FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Animals/LandAnimals/Animal') xmlData(A)
```